# get referring script file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

In Node JS, Is it possible to determine which script is requesting the current module? In other words, who is *requiring* the current script?

example:

`index.js` is requesting `helper.js`.

In `helper.js`, how can `console.log(some_referrer) == '/path/to/index.js')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. In fact `helper.js` could be required from many different scripts, but will only ever be executed once. Any time another script requires it, it will just return whatever was assigned to `module.exports` from the first time `helper.js` was included directly, without executing `helper.js` again.

You can, however, determine the original script that was run, using `require.main`. That won't tell you whether `index.js` required `other.js` which required `helper.js` or, `index.js` required `helper.js` directly. But it does tell you that `index.js` was the original script that was executed directly.

If you want `helper.js` to have different behaviour depending on how it is called, you could also export a function from `helper.js` and expect the script that requires that function to call it and pass it an argument:

```
// helper.js
module.exports = function ( arg ) {
    // Use arg to determine which action to take.
};
```

```
// index.js
require( 'helper.js' )( 1 );
```

```
// other.js
require( 'helper.js' )( 'other' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all files are in the same path.

Module1.js

```
console.log('required from --> ', require.main.filename);
```

Module2.js

```
var module1 = require('./Module1');
```

Then exec.

```
$ node Module2
$ required from -->  /path/Module2.js
```

But if you add

Module3.js

```
var module2 = require('./Module2');
```

Then.

```
$ node Module3
$ required from -->  /path/Module3.js
```

So, basically you can't, except if the script you are executing (main script) is the same which is requiring your Module1.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I can evaluate `require.main === module`. Good things happen when you rtfm :)

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module